# Determining system's unresponsiveness when high IO load

Tags: linux-kernel, btrfs, luks, io

I'm trying to understand why my Fedora 38 (KDE on Wayland) becomes unresponsive for some seconds while there's high IO on the root disk (a SanDisk SSD PLUS 240GB (UF5000RL)).
The root partition is Btrfs on LUKS (details are provided at the end of the question).

It seems like further IO activity doesn't get processed for a long time in those cases even though the IO scheduler assigned to the device is BFQ (the default one for SATA SSD in Fedora). Some apps like Firefox even crash if they attempt IO (maybe it has a watchdog if some subprocess becomes unresponsive).

This problem can happen just after I start the PC, when I log into the desktop and stuff starts loading (like the panel, the widgets and some systray apps).

The worst situation though is especially when Steam tries to update big games (in terms of storage) like Diablo 4. In practice, Steam seems to download only a delta of the changes and it composes the new files into the "downloading" directory.
Now, it usually does this thing in the same disk as the game's, but in my case that disk doesn't have enough space (it needs another ~60 GBs) so Steam decided to write those new files into my root disk.
`iostat 1` showed write bursts from 35 MB/s, up to 130 MB/s...

After researching a bit on the web, I discovered the `blktrace` tool, so I managed to trace some seconds of IO activity when another Diablo 4 patch arrived on Steam. Here's the trace parsed with `blkparse` (it shouldn't contain any personal data): https://gist.github.com/tesfabpel/eb7d0f0f6cf64aa666e3e387bb771a21

With `btt` I've managed to gather the necessary data to create 3 plots with `matplotlib` representing Queue2Device, Device2Completion and Queue2Completion (figure and summary below).

I'd like to understand whether the issue lies in my SSD (might it be failing? I noticed D2C times to be the highest, but it may be normal... I did an extended SMART self-test but it didn't find anything wrong) or some misconfiguration in LUKS / btrfs...

Do I need to extract more data from the `blktrace` traces?

This problem is driving me mad and I'd like to understand more about Linux's IO subsystem (hopefully it's useful for other people as well).

Thanks.

---

These are the settings for LUKS:

```
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          6
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          allow-discards same-cpu-crypt submit-from-crypt-cpus no-read-workqueue no-write-workqueue 

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2id
        Time cost:  4
        Memory:     1048576
        Threads:    4
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 170223
```

As you can see, I've used some flags (`allow-discards same-cpu-crypt submit-from-crypt-cpus no-read-workqueue no-write-workqueue` ) to try and speed up {en,de}cryption but it did not solve the issue.

This is the result from `cryptsetup benchmark`:

```
# Tests are approximate using memory only (no storage IO).
PBKDF2-sha1      1826787 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha256    3477864 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-sha512    1576806 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-ripemd160  805357 iterations per second for 256-bit key
PBKDF2-whirlpool  661145 iterations per second for 256-bit key
argon2i       9 iterations, 1048576 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
argon2id      9 iterations, 1048576 memory, 4 parallel threads (CPUs) for 256-bit key (requested 2000 ms time)
#     Algorithm |       Key |      Encryption |      Decryption
        aes-cbc        128b      1104.9 MiB/s      2227.6 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        128b       106.7 MiB/s       650.2 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        128b       213.5 MiB/s       377.8 MiB/s
        aes-cbc        256b       860.5 MiB/s      2125.8 MiB/s
    serpent-cbc        256b       112.1 MiB/s       645.8 MiB/s
    twofish-cbc        256b       217.6 MiB/s       376.3 MiB/s
        aes-xts        256b      2040.3 MiB/s      2059.2 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        256b       564.5 MiB/s       559.3 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        256b       345.9 MiB/s       349.2 MiB/s
        aes-xts        512b      1962.4 MiB/s      1958.9 MiB/s
    serpent-xts        512b       578.6 MiB/s       567.6 MiB/s
    twofish-xts        512b       354.4 MiB/s       353.9 MiB/s
```

`btt` results:

```
==================== All Devices ====================

            ALL           MIN           AVG           MAX           N
--------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -----------

Q2Q               0.000016862   0.174177680   9.661069906         220
Q2G               0.000002024   0.019928804   0.807080182         165
G2I               0.000001052   0.001048819   0.003998630         165
Q2M               0.000000370   0.000001245   0.000002966          42
I2D               0.000004078   0.006283935   0.168370736         109
M2D               0.001225914   0.008880338   0.074362742          28
D2C               0.000251386   1.055605439   7.040268517         135
Q2C               0.000268619   0.905934448   7.126410344         207
```

[image: btt plots]

Comment: Could it be linked with https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Btrfs#Constant_drive_activity ? You're not giving details about the BTRFS mount options you use.

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I need to check, but they were the defaults for Fedora 37... Probably `discard` isn't specified at all on fstab, so I need to check and in case add `nodiscard`... Sadly, can't check and report back until Monday...

Comment: I would check cron jobs

Comment: @Pierre-AlainTORET I've now added the `nodiscard` option but some slugginess at start is still present... Anyway these are the current mount options:  
`UUID=... /                       btrfs   subvol=root,compress=zstd:1,nodiscard,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0`  
`UUID=... /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,compress=zstd:1,nodiscard,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0`  
BTW: I've updated to Fedora 39, so probably I need to retest things more thoroughly again...